# Button clicks in API level 3?

Tags: android

I've written a relatively simple app, and I've been testing it out on the various different API levels created through the SDK and AVD manager in Eclipse.  It works great in all API levels except for level 3.  I have a few spinners on the front page which work just fine, but my four buttons don't seem to be working.  I've tried adding a breakpoint in one of the 'onClick' methods that I specified in my xml layout file, but the breakpoint never seems to get reached.  I'm kind of at a loss here.  Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Level 3 does not support the onClick attribute in XML. Unfortunately, you'll have to wire up OnClickListeners in code.

... or drop support for 1.5. It's a small and shrinking [part of the market](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html).

Comment: Ah, well that would do it!  Thank you very much - I'll probably just drop 1.5 support.